# Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\ApiController::showAll() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I want to to retrieve all buyers for a specific saller.When I remove pluck and others methods chaining after get method it's working. But is not exact thing that I want. How Can I solve this provlem?

[image: database structure]
<sub>(source: [licdn.com](https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5622AQGd-7ot6ZUmTw/feedshare-shrink_800/0?e=1573689600&v=beta&t=bk4bkQYsJ0NGaL693s07dXHCm63FTUqLCnT01LJMBWs))</sub>

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Seller;

use App\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
use App\Seller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SellerBuyerController extends ApiController
{
    
    public function index(Seller $seller)
    {
        $buyers = $seller->products()
                ->whereHas('transactions')
                ->with('transactions.buyer')
                ->get()->pluck('transactions')
                ->collapse()->pluck('buyer')
                ->unique('id')
                ->values();

        return $this->showAll($buyers);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse($collection, $code);
    }

    protected function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

}
```

Seller model hasMany relation to products

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\SellerScope;

class Seller extends User
{

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Product Model hasMany relation to transactions

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'description', 'quantity', 'status', 'image', 'seller_id',
    ];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }

}
```

Transaction Model and relation to buyer

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Transaction extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'quantity', 'buyer_id', 'product_id'
    ];

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Buyer::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Laravel version 6.0

Comment: can you show your models' relationship methods?

Comment: @ShahadatHossain edit your question and put code in there, not in a comment!

Comment: What about looking at the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing an import at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

otherwise it assumes `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` is to be used.

And `values()` obviously returns the support collection, not an eloquent one.

Comment: Does not make sense to get the same error. Just try it and share the other error because it cannot be the same 100%

Comment: use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;  I imported it instead if use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Comment: Thanks a lot @nakov

Comment: @ShahadatHossain there is an option to accept the answer as well of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship from `Buyer` to `Transaction` you can go at this from the other direction to get buyers. You also need to make sure there is a relationship from `Product` to `Seller` (make sure you have the inverse of every relationship setup)

```
Buyer::whereHas('transactions.products.seller', function ($query) use ($seller) {
    $query->where('id', $seller->id); // might have to be a more specific key name
})->get();
```

You would end up with a Eloquent Collection of Buyers who have transactions including products from a particular seller.

Answer (score 0):

you should put `use Illuminate\Support\Collection;` in folder traits over apiResponser.php